# Have to keep running view:clear otherwise I get a permission denied error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, apache2, homestead

Each time I edit a blade file I have to run `php artisan view:clear` in order for the page to load correctly otherwise I get the following error

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/Code/app/storage/framework/views/fsfsawe8bde92c95bad12ddfcfaea1738afsac0.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied (View: /home/vagrant/Code/app/resources/views/header.blade.php)
```

I am using the following:

- Homestead v7.14.2
- Vagrant (2.1.2)

I also recently ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` on my vm.
The Homestead update script did not install php 7.2 so I did that manually.

The permissions on my storage folders are all 777.

How do I setup laravel so that I do not have to keep running `php artisan view:clear` each time I make a change?

Answer (score 1):

What has worked for me regarding this same issue, is to change apache or nginx to run as your local user or another that you have created and then change the laravel application directory ownership to this user using a chmod user -R. Or conversely you could change the project ownership to the web server user account.

Comment: Thanks. This helped point me in the right direction. In the end I completely reinstalled my vagrant laravel box and the problem solved itself.